# Broadcast to devices connected to hotspot AP

Tags: android, networking

I need some clues how to approach my app. I have android device which provides HotSpot/AccessPoint for other devices. And this device which provides hotspot for others wants to get some data from internet and broadcast this data to devices which are connected to this hotspot. Ofcourse all smartphones must have installed same app.

Is there way to achieve that?

Thanks You!

Comment: Please do not do it that way. Broadcast is really obsolete, and IPv6 does not have broadcast so your application would not be able to be ported to it. The modern way is to use multicast. Broadcast interrupts _every_ host on a LAN, even those not interested, but multicast only interrupts those interested.

Comment: Thank you Ron for your respond. Do you mean to use WifiManager.MulticastLock?

Comment: I mean that you pick a specific multicast group, probably in the Organization-Local scope (`239.0.0.0/8`), the hosts will listen to that multicast group, and the server will send the traffic destined to that multicast group.

Comment: Could you help how can i determine this device which provide hotspot for others, and only this device will be able send data to devices connected to it

Comment: Any device could send multicast to a multicast group, but there are 16,777,216 multicast groups in the Organization-Local scope, so it is unlikely that anything else will use the particular group you choose. Multicast is confined to the LAN, so outside devices will not be sending multicast to your LAN.

Comment: Sure i understand, but i have no idea how to setup my application that only device which is providing internet (hotspot) for this LAN will be able to send multicast and others will be able only to listen for new messages or other data

Comment: The hosts should be configured to listen on the multicast group, and the server will send on the multicast group. There are questions with answers here that explain how to do that for various languages.